# choco uninstall just removing package not Application

Tags: uninstallation, chocolatey

choco uninstall just removing package not Application from Control Panel "Programs and features" I have only chocoinstall.ps1 where i have managed uninstallation.

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey manages packages. Packages manage software. Chocolatey doesn't manage the software.

Chocolatey will uninstall the package, and it's the packages' responsibility to uninstall the software.

So Chocolatey did the right thing here. However, my suggestion would be to contact the maintainer by:

1. Going to the package page on the [Community Repository](https://community.chocolatey.org/pacakges).
2. Searching for the package and then click it in the list.
3. Click the 'Contact Maintainers' link on that page (left-hand side, near the top) and let them know their package does not uninstall the software.

You can skip steps 1 and 2 if you know the package page URL.